# multiple shape objects with as3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, object

hey i want to be able to create multiple shapes and store them perhaps in an array to be able to dynamically move them and change them.
is there a way to have a shape object and store it an array?
so that i can do something like shapeArray[0].x =100
current code

```
for(var i=0; i<10; i++){
var sprite:Sprite=new Sprite();

sprite.graphics.lineStyle(1)
sprite.graphics.drawCircle(0,0,10)
sprite.graphics.endFill();
addChild(sprite)
}
```

many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [Vector](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Vector.html) class, you could use:

```
var shapeArray:Vector.<Sprite> = new Vector.<Sprite>();
for(var i=0; i<10; i++){
    var sprite:Sprite=new Sprite(); 
    sprite.graphics.lineStyle(1)
    sprite.graphics.drawCircle(0,0,10)
    sprite.graphics.endFill();
    addChild(sprite);

    shapeArray.push( sprite );
}
```